# How to create sh script with expect?

Tags: embedded, sh, embedded-linux, expect

I'm trying to create a sh script using expect script for embedded system (I don't want to change firmware to include this script). So, I have the following script, which doesn't work because of wrong usage of `val` in `if`-block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set timeout 20
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet $ipaddr
expect "soc1 login: "
send "root\n"
expect "prompt # "
send "val=`some_command`\n"
expect "prompt # "
send "if [ \$val -eq 0 ]; then echo Good; fi\n"
# its here ^^^^^
expect "prompt # "
send "exit\n"
interact
```

I've tried to use `$$` and it doesn't help.
How to fix this script to allow usage of variables inside sh script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of the script is in the [interpretation by Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11) of `[` and `]` - these brackets should be escaped:

```
send "if \[ \$val -eq 0 \]; then echo Good; fi\n"
# its here ^^^^^
```